# Induction with extra variable and conditional proposition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction

Could someone take a look at the following proposition I'm trying to prove? Note: I'm required to use induction, strong induction, or proof by smallest counter example. My approach was to use regular induction.

My proof is not complete but could someone see what I have so far and tell me if I'm on the right track? This may be way off base since up until now I've only been working proof by induction problems that start with something along the lines of "For every integer $n$..." or "If $n\in\mathbb{N}$..." etc.

$Proposition$ Suppose $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $5\mid2^na$ implies $5\mid a$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

$Proof$. We will prove this using mathematical induction.

*Base Case*. Let $n=1$. Then $5\mid2^{(1)}a$ which simplifies to $5\mid2a$. This means $2a=5b$ where $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since the LHS of our equation is even, we know $b$ must be even as well. So $b=2c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $2a=5(2c)=2(5c)$. Dividing this equation by $2$ gives $a=5c$. Therfore $5\mid a$.

*Inductive Step.* Let the natural number $n=k\ge1$. We need to show that if $5 \mid 2^ka$ implies $5\mid a$ then $5 \mid 2^{k+1}a$ implies $5\mid a$. We will use direct proof.

This is far as I've gotten.

[ADDED]

So then the Inductive Step would unfold as:

*Inductive Step.* Let the natural number $n=k\ge1$. We need to show that if $5 \mid 2^ka$ implies $5\mid a$ then $5 \mid 2^{k+1}a$ implies $5\mid a$. We will use direct proof.

Let us assume the statement $5\mid 2^ka$ implies $5\mid a$ is true. Now suppose $5\mid2^{k+1}a$. Observe that $2^{k+1}a=2\cdot2^ka=2a'$ where $a'=2^ka$. Since we know $5\mid2a'$ then it must be the case that $5\mid a'$ since $2$ is even. By our inductive hypothesis if $5\mid a'$ and $a'=2^ka$ then it follows that $5\mid a$.

But if $5\mid2^ka$ implies $5\mid a$, which in turn implies that $5\mid2^{k+1}a$ implies $5\mid a$, we know that if $5\mid2^na$ then $5\mid a$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. $\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did so far is very good. Now suppose that holds for $k$ and suppose that $5\mid 2^{k+1}a$. Note that $2^{k+1}a=2\times 2^ka=2a'$ where $a'=2^ka$. You know that your proposition holds for $1$ and $k$...

Comment: Thanks! Can you take a look at my inductive step now beneath the section titled "[ADDED]" and let me know what you think? Is the wording OK?

Comment: You're welcome! What you wrote is good :) One small detail about the conclusion: I found "if $5\mid2^ka$ implies $5\mid a$, which in turn implies that $5\mid2^{k+1}a$ implies $5\mid a$" quite confusing. "if $5\mid2^ka\Rightarrow 5\mid a$ implies  $5\mid2^{k+1}a\Rightarrow 5\mid a$" might be better. Usually, in order to avoid repetition, the formula to be proven by induction is noted $P(k)$, in which case you can simply write "if $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$".

Comment: You're probabely learning how to write proofs, so writing such a conclusion might be important, but in reality in many proofs by induction that concluding phrase isn't mentioned. After assuming $P(k)$, once $P(k+1)$ is proven to hold, that's the end of the proof, or the sentence "By the Principle of Mathematical Induction, the proof is complete." instead like in [this proof.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Cubes#Proof_by_Induction)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is
not was asked,
but using induction
to prove that result
somehow seems wrong,
like using a hammer to
open a bottle.

So,
I decided to see
if I could come up with
a proof of the
"correct" theorem,
and here's what I got:

Theorem:

Suppose $c | ab$
and
$(c, b) = 1$.
Prove that
$c | a$.

Proof.

Since
$(c, b) = 1$,
there are $u, v$
such that
$uc-bv = 1$.

Since $c | ab$,
there is a $k$
such that
$ab = ck$.

Since
$uc=bv+ 1$,
$uca=bva+ a$.

Since
$ab = ck$,
$uca=ckv+ a$,
so that
$a 
=uca-ckv
=c(ua-kv)
$,
so that,
finally,
$c | a$.

Comment: Nice! But why $uc-bv=1$? Why not $1=uc+bv$ The final step would then be a bit simpler.

Since $1=uc+bv$, $a=uca+bva$. Then $a=acu+(ab)v=acu+ckv=c(au+kv)$ and therefore $c\mid a$.

Wouldn't this eliminate the need to subtract ckv from the LHS of the equation at the end?

Comment: Eh, six of one, eight of another.

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon that's not really important. $u$ and $v$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$. You can see $uc-bv$ as $uc+b(-v)=uc+bv'$.